# why does autovacuum not vacuum my table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, autovacuum

There is one table in my schema that does not get autovacuumed. If I run `VACUUM posts;` on the table the vacuum process finishes nicely, but the autovacuum daemon never vacuums the table for some reason.
Is there a way to find out why? What could be possible reasons for this?

[image: table stats]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is just fine, nothing to worry.

The table is the only medium sized one (3 million rows).

Autovacuum will kick in if the number of dead tuples more than `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor` (default: 0.2) of your live tuples, so if more than 20% of your table has been deleted or updated.

This is usually just fine, and I would not change it. But if you want to do it for some reason, you can do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE posts SET (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.1);
```